# Character driven and application layer functions are not associated?

Tags: c, linux

I have added a character device to the Linux 3.10 kernel source code. When I use `insmod spiio.ko`, I can find `spiio0` under `/dev`. At this time, I can also see the relevant printing using `dmesg`, such as the printing in function `spiio_probe`. However, when I open it using `test_spiio.c` (test code), I cannot find the relevant printing, as if I did not call the `spiio_drv_open` function in `spiio.c` (driver code). What is the problem?

dmesg:

```
...
[ 2178.342170] gpio remove ...
[ 2208.086389] gpio count:1
[ 2208.086833] gpio is ok, registered GPIO: 266
...
```

spiio.c (driver code):

```c
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/platform_device.h>
#include <linux/of.h>
#include <linux/of_gpio.h>
#include <linux/gpio.h>
#include <linux/sys_config.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>

#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/miscdevice.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/major.h>
#include <linux/mutex.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/seq_file.h>
#include <linux/stat.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/tty.h>
#include <linux/kmod.h>
#include <linux/gfp.h>


static int major = 0;
static struct class *spiio_class;
static int spiio_gpio;


static ssize_t spiio_drv_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t size, loff_t *offset)
{
        int value = gpio_get_value(spiio_gpio);
        printk("read value is %d\n", value);
    return value;
}

/* write(fd, &val, 1); */
static ssize_t spiio_drv_write(struct file *file, const char __user *buf, size_t size, loff_t *offset)
{
        #if 0
    int err;
    char status;
    err = copy_from_user(&status, buf, 1);
    /* 根据次设备号和status控制spiio */
    gpio_set_value(spiio_gpio, status);
    printk("this is write");
    return 1;
        #endif
   return -1;
}

static int spiio_drv_open(struct inode *node, struct file *file)
{
    
        // gpio_direction_output(spiio_gpio, 0);
        gpio_direction_input(spiio_gpio);
        printk("this is open\n");
    return 0;
}

static int spiio_drv_close(struct inode *node, struct file *file)
{
    return 0;
}

static long spiio_drv_ioctl(struct file *filp, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
    /*================================================*/
    // 待实现msleep或者mdelay
    /*================================================*/
        printk("this is ioctl\n");
        return 0;
}


static struct file_operations spiio_drv = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = spiio_drv_open,
    .read = spiio_drv_read,
    .write = spiio_drv_write,
    .release = spiio_drv_close,
    .unlocked_ioctl = spiio_drv_ioctl,
};

int spiio_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    struct device_node *nd = pdev->dev.of_node;
    struct gpio_config config;
    printk("gpio count:%d\n", of_gpio_named_count(nd, "spiio_gpio"));
    spiio_gpio = of_get_named_gpio_flags(nd, "spiio_gpio", 0, (enum of_gpio_flags *)&config);
    if (!gpio_is_valid(spiio_gpio))
        printk("gpio isn't valid\n");
    if (gpio_request(spiio_gpio, pdev->name) < 0)
        printk("gpio request faispiio %d\n", spiio_gpio);

    major = register_chrdev(0, "spiio", &spiio_drv); /* /dev/spiio */

    spiio_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "spiio_class");
    if (IS_ERR(spiio_class))
    {
        printk("%s %s line %d\n", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
        unregister_chrdev(major, "spiio");
        gpio_free(spiio_gpio);
        return PTR_ERR(spiio_class);
    }
    device_create(spiio_class, NULL, MKDEV(major, 0), NULL, "spiio%d", 0); /* /dev/100ask_spiio0 */
    printk("gpio is ok, registered GPIO: %d\n", spiio_gpio);
    return 0;
}

int spiio_remove(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    device_destroy(spiio_class, MKDEV(major, 0));
    class_destroy(spiio_class);
    unregister_chrdev(major, "spiio");
    gpio_free(spiio_gpio);
    printk("gpio remove ...\n");
    return 0;
}

struct of_device_id ids[] = {
    {.compatible = "dobot, spiio"},
    {},
};
/* 1. 定义platform_driver */
static struct platform_driver chip_demo_gpio_driver = {
    .probe = spiio_probe,
    .remove = spiio_remove,
    .driver = {
        .name = "spiio",
        .of_match_table = ids,
    },
};

static int __init spiio_init(void)
{
    int err;
    err = platform_driver_register(&chip_demo_gpio_driver);
    return err;
}

static void __exit spiio_exit(void)
{
    platform_driver_unregister(&chip_demo_gpio_driver);
}
module_init(spiio_init);
module_exit(spiio_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

test_spiio.c (test code):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
char *spiio_path = "/dev/spiio0";
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd;
    char ioStatus = -1;

    /* 打开文件 */
    fd = open(spiio_path, O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        printf("can not open file %s\n", spiio_path);
        return -1;
    }

    ssize_t byteRead;
    byteRead = read(fd, &ioStatus, sizeof(ioStatus));

    printf("byteRead is %d, io status is %d\n", byteRead, ioStatus);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```